# Handling python error in bash script with no error codes

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, papermill

I am running a python cli tool, Papermill. I am running jupyter notebooks and want to be able to detect assertionErrors when the notebook are ran. When I run papermill from a bash script I always get a 0 exit code, even when there is a python error in the notebook.

I've found methods for detecting the exit code which work, but python errors are not throwing any codes

For example: in my nbTest.sh I am running the notebook and looking for an error

```
papermill python_notebooks/testing/$d python_notebooks/testing/results/$d.results.ipynb || True
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "Successfully executed script"
else
  # Redirect stdout from echo command to stderr.
  echo "Script exited with error." 
fi
done
```

and as output I am getting:

```
.
.
.
Input Notebook:  python_notebooks/testing/paperTest.ipynb
Output Notebook: python_notebooks/testing/results/paperTest.ipynb.results.ipynb
 83%|████████▎ | 5/6 [00:00<00:00,  1.97it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception encountered at "In [5]":
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d941c6663321> in <module>()
----> 1 assert passed == False

AssertionError: 
Successfully executed script
```

I would expect an exit code of 1 but python failures aren't handled

Comment: you can use explicit `exit(1)`.

Comment: Isn't it better to handle error inside your python code? Something like `try:
    assert True
    assert 7 == 7
    assert 1 == 2
    # many more statements like this
except AssertionError:
    _, _, tb = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.print_tb(tb) # Fixed format
    tb_info = traceback.extract_tb(tb)
    filename, line, func, text = tb_info[-1]

    print('An error occurred on line {} in statement {}'.format(line, text))
    exit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Part of the beauty of the Jupyter and papermill combo is the errors are preserved in the notebook and location of where they occurred. This is very helpful when running multiple ETL jobs at once. If you also want access to the errors outside of the notebook, I would write the specific errors out to a `errors.txt` file from inside of a `try catch`. Then your script can finish by reading off the errors, if any.

Various error logging techniques are discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383865/how-to-log-error-to-file-and-not-fail-on-exception).